# Trigger same query multiple times with apollo client fetchMore Apollo Client and append the data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I converted a class component into a function component to make use of React Hooks. The graphQl query is called as follows:

```
const { data, error, loading, fetchMore } = useQuery(getAll, {
            variables: { 
                code: props.code,
                type: props.type,
                page: 0 
            }
        });
```

`fetchMore` function is what I'm looking for. I checked several tutorial, they all implement the `fetchMore` function on *onClick* trigger.

My question is:

Is it possible to call `fetchMore` without trigger an event? So that it's called conditionally when a variable is set?

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested I tried the `useEffect` hook. Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(data != null) {
            const { nextLink } = data.list.nextLink;

            if(nextLink !== []){
                fetchMore({
                    variables: { 
                        code: props.code,
                        type: props.type,
                        page: page+1  
                    },
                    updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                      fetchMoreResult.list = [
                        ...prevResult.list,
                        ...fetchMoreResult.list
                      ];
                      return fetchMoreResult;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

However it calls the query only once. How can I trigger that query multiple times until *nextLink* is not empty? And then update the results?

**UPDATE 2**

After some work I'm able to call all the pages and fetch the data. Here is what I did.

I added the *page* field in the backend query, which is used as a variable to be passed back and forth to the query calls. Moreover, this page variable is increased at each call. Also, the fetchmore function is called only when *nextLink* is empty. However, currently the page display only the last page results, since the new result replace the old data.

Here is the code:

```
let [hasNext, setHasNext] = useState(true);
    useEffect(() => {
            if(data != null) {
                const { nextLink, page } = data.list;
                let isNext = (nextLink !== "") ? true : false;
                setHasNext(isNext);
    
                if(hasNext){
                    const { data } = fetchMore({
                        variables: { 
                            code: props.code,
                            type: props.type,
                            page: parseInt(page)
                        },
                        updateQuery: (prevResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                            fetchMoreResult = {
                                ...prevResult,
                                ...fetchMoreResult,
                            };
                            return fetchMoreResult;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

The *spread operator* doesn't seem to work. How can I append the new data fetched to the old results?

Comment: why compose, not hooks? a bit 'ancient technique' ... why not compose from react-apollo ... https://github.com/git-ly/sportsstore/blob/194143eadc8d828c6f305a697cd9414a1d57f434/src/admin/OrdersConnector.js#L10 - check data/props flow

Comment: I'm still not using hooks, otherwise I have to rewrite the component. I'm moving to hooks with new components. Isn't there a way to do it without hooks? With the `Query` component maybe?

Comment: INHO components aren't better option ... didn't used it by choice, I skipped this option (as not readable, limiting etc.) from HOCs to hooks

Comment: use useEffect hook

Comment: ehhh ...*'called conditionally when a variable is set'* ... what changes here? ... useState ... update in interval until some condition

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: find some react counter example with timeout

Comment: Could you be more specific? Currently I'm able to call all the pages until the last one. However, I need to update the new result with the old one, since currently the new data replace the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some attempts, here is my solution. As suggested in the comments, to trigger the same query multiple times I should use `fetchMore` inside the `useEffect` hook.

Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(data != null) {
            if(data.list !== []){
                const { nextLink, page } = data.list;
                let isNext = (nextLink !== "") ? true : false;
                setHasNext(isNext);

                if(hasNext && page != null){
                    const { data } = fetchMore({
                        variables: { 
                            code: props.code,
                            type: props.type,
                            page: page
                        },
                        updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                            if (!fetchMoreResult) {
                                return prev;
                            }
                            return {
                                list: {
                                    ...prev.list,
                                    ...fetchMoreResult.list,
                                    array: [
                                        ...prev.list.array,
                                        ...fetchMoreResult.list.array,
                                    ],
                                },
                            };
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    setLoadingState(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The graphQL query is as follows:

```
query($code: String, $type: Int, $page: Int) {
    list(code: $code, type: $type, page: $page) {
        array {
            ID
            title
            field_firstname
            field_lastname
        }
        nextLink
        page
    }
}
```

Comment: then it was about response/data structure and updating in 'immutable way' .... `parseInt(page)` shouldn't be required as received 'page' should be an integer - check network response